# SourceTree Push failure

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have run into a error while trying to Push to my repository.

I am fairly new to this so any help will be very welcome. The error occurs when I Push my master branch, the loading bar goes red and part of the error message states:

" ![rejected] master->master(non-fast-forward)
   error:failed to push refs to 'https://...my_path.git' "

I have tried to attach an image by I was unable to so I supplied a link to the image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4F8L.png) if the error message isn't sufficient.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The important part in your question is the hint given in the image you uploaded. Could you please attach it as a text or `code text` here so anybody in this question can easily see the problem (and so that it may help others as well)

Comment: Thanks tryman, the hits given in the error message can be seen below:

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0):

The master branch you're pushing to has changed. You need to synch your local repo with the remote first then you can push your changes to it.

You need to run `git pull origin master` first.